# VBA looping through range and changing #N/A cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am fairly new to visual basic.  I am trying to loop through a column and change all of the #N/A's.  I want to alternate every other #N/A so the first gets changed to type 1 and then the next to type 2, and so on.  I am running into some trouble and was wondering if someone could put me in the right direction.  Here is what I have so far and thanks in advance!

```
Sub TruckFilterType()

Dim counter As Integer
Dim state As Integer

counter = 2
state = 1

For counter = 2 To 100
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter, 1).Value = "#N/A" Then
        If state = 1 Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter, 1).Value = "TYPE 1"
            state = 2

        ElseIf state = 2 Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter, 1).Value = "TYPE 2"
            state = 1
        End If
    End If
Next counter

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to see if a cell contains `#NA` you need to trap the error.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub TruckFilterType()

Dim counter As Long
Dim state As Long
Dim CellVal As Variant

counter = 2
state = 1

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For counter = 2 To 100
        ' trap #NA error section
        On Error Resume Next
        CellVal = .Cells(counter, 1).Value2
        On Error GoTo 0
        If IsError(CellVal) Then
            If CellVal = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then ' check if current error if xlErrNA (2042)
                If state = 1 Then
                    .Cells(counter, 1).Value = "TYPE 1"
                    state = 2
                Else
                    .Cells(counter, 1).Value = "TYPE 2"
                    state = 1
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next counter
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome.  I think I understand everything expect the line "On Error GoTo 0".  Could you explain that?

Comment: @DustinSmith here's a link to the expert http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm